# Check Similarity and relevance between two Object

Tags: node.js, object

I'm working on a project that deal with merging list of words

Object are at this format

```
const obj = {words: [{name: "test", occurence: 10}...]}
```

The objectif in the end is to get only one object that contains all words from other object and this is done.

But some object are too differente because it contain words that are not the sames or not in the same number and so I don't want to merge theme.

Have you any solution to find those object that false my data ?

```
const obj = {words: [{word: 'cars', occurence: 10}, {word: 'engine', occurence: 3}, {word: 'speed', occurence: 2}]}

const obj2 = {words: [{word: 'boat', occurence: 10}, {word: 'sea', occurence: 2}, {word: 'ocean', occurence: 2}]}

const obj3 = {words: [{word: 'cars', occurence: 5}, {word: 'engine', occurence: 2}, {word: 'race', occurence: 1}]}

checkSimilarity(obj, obj2) // return false

checkSimilarity(obj, obj3) // return true
```

Thanks

Comment: title suggest similarity and relevant is between objects but the body of the question talks about the differences between words and theme. This is way too confusing to warrant any form of answer.

Comment: My objective is to merge object that contain words -> I don't want to find similarity between words, I want to know If the object B can be merge with A if they are similare

Comment: What does similar mean? at least name or occurence to be in common?

Comment: Maybe edit your question in such a way that you show source data and the results you want to end up with.

Comment: well I don't know at this point. For the project those words are keywords from a webpage, I need to get Keywords that define the website and so I merge keywords from pages but I don't want to merge page of the website that talk about irrelevant subject like rules laws login ..